# Relationship Weierstrass elliptic function, Jacobi elliptic functions

Tags: special-functions, elliptic-functions

[On Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_elliptic_function#Relation_to_Jacobi%27s_elliptic_functions), one finds a relation between the *Weierstrass elliptic function* and *Jacobi's elliptic functions* as

$$
\wp(z; g_2; g_3) = e_3 + \frac{e_1 - e_2}{sn^2 w}
$$

where $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$ are the roots of the cubic polynomial

$$
4 \wp^3(z) -g_2 \wp(z) - g_3.
$$

The modulus and argument of the Jacobi functions are
$$
k = \sqrt{\frac{e_2-e_3}{e_1-e_3}}; \quad w = z \sqrt{e_1 - e_3}.
$$

It seems to me that the roots $e_i$ are generally complex-valued. Is that correct? If yes, what branch of the sqrt is one to take for $k$ and $w$? How are Jacobi elliptic functions defined for complex modulus anyway?

Comment: Since $\,\text{sn}(w)^2 = w^2 -(1+k^2)w^4/3 +2+13k^2+2k^4)w^6/45 + \cdots,\,$ there is no branch problem for $w$ or $k$.

Comment: @Somos Right, nice observation! Do you know how Jacobi elliptic functions are defined for complex modulus at all?

Comment: The DLMF chapter 22 [Jacobian Elliptic Functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/22.2) equation 22.2.4 states $\text{sn}(z,k) = \frac{\theta_3(0,q)}{\theta_2(0,q)}\frac{\theta_1(\zeta,q)}{\theta_4(\zeta,q)}$ where $\zeta=\frac{\pi z}{2K(k)}$. The theta functions are defined in 20.2(i) as infinite series.